# How do I use a C++ static library in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, static-libraries, wrapper, objective-c++

I have a c++ static libray: `.a` file and `staticLibrary.h` file.

In the .h file, there is a class I want to access:

```
typedef enum
{
    eStaticLibOperationUnknown               = 0
    eStaticLibOperationSystemCheck           = 1
} enumStaticLibOperation;

typedef enum
{
    eStaticLibResultUnknown              = 0,
    eStaticLibResultNullParameter        = 4,
    eStaticLibResultWrongParameter       = 5
} enumStaticLibResult;

typedef std::function<void(void)> typeCallBack;

class classResultHelper
{
    blah blah
};

class staticLibrary
{
public:
      staticLibrary(typeCallBack, const char*);

      void requestOperation(const char*, size_t);
      void requestOperation(enumStaticLibOperation, const char*, size_t);
      enumStaticLibResult getResult(char**, size_t*);
};
```

I used `#import "staticLibrary.h"` at the top of my viewController.m file. This raised an error as it recognized the C++ to be foreign. I then changed the viewController to a .mm extension, making the file Objective-C++ and removing the error.

But when I try to run `staticLibrary* sL = [[staticLibrary alloc] init];` in viewDidLoad, I get an error at the second staticLibrary on the right side. It says "receiver type is not an objective-c class". What am I doing wrong?

When looking at the documentation for using the static library it says:

```
1.1. new staticLibrary(callback, “en”);
1.2. requestOperation(“enumSystemcheck”, NULL, 0);
1.3. callback();
1.4. getResult(... , ...);"
```

I believe this is Java (?), and the first line is to make an instance of staticLibrary with those parameters. How would I do that in objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have in the example isn't Java, it's C++. ObjC++ means that you can mix statements made in C++ or ObjC on a line, it doesn't mean you can use C++ objects as if they were ObjC objects, or with the ObjC syntax.

What people usually do is only include C++ headers and write C++ code in the .mm file itself, and not put any in the header. Write an ObjC class that wraps the part of your C++ library that you want. So in your example, that'd be something like:

**JCRStaticLibrary.h**

```
@interface JCRStaticLibrary : NSObject
-(instancetype) initWithCallback: (void(^)(void))inObjCCallback;
-(void) requestOperation: (NSString*)what withBuffer: (void*)buf size: (int)theSize;
@end
```

**JCRStaticLibrary.mm**

```
#import "JCRStaticLibrary.h"
#include "staticLibrary.h"

@interface JCRStaticLibrary ()
{
    staticLibrary *_cppStaticLibrary;
}
@end

@implementation JCRStaticLibrary

-(instancetype) initWithCallback: (void(^)(void))inObjCCallback
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self )
    {
        _staticLibrary = new staticLibrary( inObjCCallback, "en"); // ObjC++ knows how to turn an ObjC block into a C++ lambda.
        // Under the hood it generates code like:
        // _staticLibrary = new staticLibrary( [inObjCCallback](){ inObjCCallback(); }, "en");
        // Where the [inObjCCallback](){} part is how C++ does lambdas, its equivalent to blocks.
        // I.e. it's roughly analogous to ObjC's ^(){}.
    }
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    delete _staticLibrary;
}

-(void) requestOperation: (NSString*)what withBuffer: (void*)buf size: (int)theSize
{
    _staticLibrary->requestOperation( [what UTF8String], buf, theSize );
}

@end
```

Something like that. I don't know what the parameters to requestOperation in your case actually are, so I just made an educated guess.

Instead of passing in the ObjC block to `-initWithCallback:`, you could also write your own lambda and make it a method, i.e.:

```
-(instancetype) init
{
    __weak JCRStaticLibrary *weakSelf = self; // Avoid retain circle.
    _staticLibrary = new staticLibrary( [weakSelf](){ [weakSelf doCallbackThing]; }, "en"); // ObjC++ knows how to turn an ObjC block into a C++ lambda.
}

-(void) doCallbackThing
{
    // Do whatever the callback should do here.
}
```

It really depends on whether the callback changes every time you create an object of this type (e.g. if a JCRStaticLibrary object represents a command sent over the network) or comes from a small set of commands used over and over again (e.g. you receive a video frame and apply a filter to it, then hand it off to another object, so you really only ever have one callback). In the former case you wanna keep the block, in the latter, having a subclass for each filter *might* make more sense (unless you want to switch between filters on-the-fly).

Comment: Alright this clarified a lot! So I first wrap the C++ code in an Obj-C class, then I make calls to the wrapper. I attempted to do it but I got errors on the "callback". I added more code so it would be clearer. I'm not sure how to declare the typedef callback from the C++ into the obj-c. I also don't know how to reference the "enumStaticLibResult" and "enumStaticLibOperation". Some clarification on translating the C++ to Obj-C could really help me!

Comment: Usually, when a callback (usually a function or an object that can be treated like a function (like a functor, lambda or block) is expected, you write one like you would in C++, pass along a pointer to your object, and then call a method on your object instead from inside that callback. Then anyone who uses it from ObjC can just override that method.

Comment: As to enums, you need to translate them somehow into enums that exist in ObjC, either by mapping them to equivalent constants that already exist, or by defining your own enum. Strictly spoken, most enums work the same way in C++ and ObjC (because both do basic enums like C used to do them), so you could just use the ones from C++, but since they are in a C++ header, you wouldn't be able to use your ObjC class in straight ObjC code then, because the header also contains C++ code.

Comment: A quick-and-dirty way to have the enums would probably be to just copy the enums from the C++ header and rename them slightly (e.g. by adding an ObjC-style prefix, like I used JCR in the above example), and as long as they map to the same numbers, you should be able to typecast one into the other before returning it.

Comment: Wow thanks! I'm not sure if I fully understood it though (I have no prior C++ experience). Could you point to some good resources to tackle this better? Or maybe update the code in your post in relation to the code I added to my post? I just want to wrap this up, no pun intended, and get the wrapper finished :P

Comment: No time, but 2 short notes: 1) The callback is a lambda (std::function), which is bridged to ObjC blocks by the ObjC++ compiler, so you can rewrite this to the equivalent Block in your ObjC method, then pass that Block into the C++ code and all should be fine. 2) If you plan to use C++ code, you won't be able to avoid having to learn C++.

Comment: If ever you get the time to clarify things, it would be much appreciated. Thank you for the help, I will try to research up on C++ and using pointers.